# Do a debounce with Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, lodash, debouncing

I sorta wish to make something like this with firebase functions

[image]

but **slower**. So I write to the realtime DB and after some minutes it will set to `false`.

This is my attempt:

```
const debounce = require('lodash.debounce') // "^4.0.8"
...
exports.deviceConnected = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const now = `${format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}`
  return admin
    .database()
    .ref('connected')
    .set(now)
    .then(() => response.send(`Connected updated ${now}`))
})

function deviceDisconnect() {
  admin
    .database()
    .ref('connected')
    .set(false)
}

exports.updateDeviceConnection = functions.database
  .ref('connected')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const connected = change.after.val()
    if (connected) {
      debounce(deviceDisconnect(), 7000, {
        leading: false,
        trailing: true,
      })
    }
    return true
  })
```

For developing purpose I'm using 7 sec (7000 msec). The first trigger seems slow, but after that it's immediate and no debouncing.

[image: firebase example of the issue]

Comment: I think you're going to have trouble with this sort of thing as it requires that you maintain state between each of your function invocations. Cloud Functions are stateless by nature.  On top of that, Cloud Functions will shut down your function and all of its unfinished async work as soon as they terminate.  Bear in mind also that you need to pay attention to all the promises returned by various API calls - you can't leave a promise "dangling", or it may never finish because CF will shut it down.

Comment: If you want state, you're going to have to implement that yourself using something persistent, like the database itself.  So maybe you want to store a timestamp somewhere that lets the next invocation know what happened previously. These writes should be protected by a transaction.  You will not be able to use lodash, as it requires state and doesn't give you a promise to work with.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you very much for your comment. I found that I did not need this self-killing-robot feature anyway.